# DNS issue when using Docker

Tags: docker

From a Spring Boot application running on a docker container, I am trying to connect to Rabbit MQ, Storm and other services which are also running on a docker container. It is working fine when using IP address like x.x.x.x but the same is not working when using the DNS name for that IP. In the command prompt I am able to ping and get a successful response for the same DNS name. Requesting for your help and support in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you can resolve DNS on the command line.  If you mean the command line of the host machine (outside of of the docker container), then the issue is probably with the container's own DNS settings.

A container has it's own network settings.  Take a look at the /etc/resolv.conf file being used by the Spring Boot container - this will show you that container's DNS settings.